# How do you stop linqpad from displaying the output of statements written to Debug.Writeline?

Tags: c#, debugging, linqpad

Linqpad seems to put a listener into the debug.listeners collection and then present the outputs of trace to the results window, along side any of the results from the query itself.

Is there a way of telling linqpad not to do this but to leave the existing debug.listeners collection alone?

I have an assembly I'm calling from linqpad which writes trace out to a separate application but it appears that linqpad clears down the listeners and puts its own in, ideally I would like the existing listeners left in tact so I get our normal trace out of the library.

Thanks for any suggestions
Tollo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to Edit | Preferences | Advanced, and select 'Always use fresh app domains', does it make any difference?

Comment: That worked, it no longer seems to either disable our trace listeners or put the output into the results window :) I set Always Use Fresh Application Domains to true.  Not sure what that does but it seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.

I am referencing a third party library (Google.GData.YouTube) that is outputting a bunch of trace information that I don't want. Joe's solution didn't work for me but the question gave me a clue and I worked around the problem by adding the following to my query.

```
Debug.Listeners[0].Dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks; although that didn't work for me I used `Debug.Listeners.Clear();` and it worked.

Comment: Note that full namespace is System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners.Clear();